# SQL Server 2014 Aggregate Event Durations by Half Hour Intervals

Tags: sql-server

I have a set of data from which I need to break up multiple different event durations into one or more 30 minute time intervals for each event (and resourceid, or owner).  The duration may span more than one half hour interval, and I need the time that the event took in just that interval.  That is where I'm running into trouble, and could not find any other question solutions that seemed to address this as I required.

I do know how to take counts by interval, but don't know how to handle the interval spanning thing in a way that is not stupid.  I'm not experienced and would greatly appreciate a good, hard shove in the right direction, because I've been thinking about this and fiddling around for two days now with nothing to show for it.  My worst case scenario was to cursor through the source data line-by-line, do the math, then insert results into the table, but I thought that was totally asinine, so didn't even try it.

Oh, and performance is not an issue...data volume is low.  Using SS 2014.

(Also, I'm sorry, I don't understand how you guy are embedding code snippets, so I apologize ahead of time for any faux pas or other idiocy).

Here's what the source data looks like (and I will put a create table/insert below, for a full day's data for one owner or resourceid, for testing):

```
ResourceID  EventType   EventStartDateTime  EventEndDateTime        Duration  
16278       6       2018-07-11 10:53:58.163 2018-07-11 11:03:58.163 600  
16278       3       2018-07-11 11:03:58.163 2018-07-11 11:16:29.970 751  
16278       4       2018-07-11 11:16:29.970 2018-07-11 11:16:33.330 4  
16278       5       2018-07-11 11:16:33.330 2018-07-11 11:24:06.977 453  
16278       6       2018-07-11 11:24:06.977 2018-07-11 11:31:31.633 445  
16278       7       2018-07-11 11:31:31.633 2018-07-11 11:31:31.633 0  
16278       1       2018-07-11 12:30:44.020 2018-07-11 17:15:55.173 17111  
16278       2       2018-07-11 12:30:44.023 2018-07-11 12:33:23.437 159  
16278       3       2018-07-11 12:33:23.437 2018-07-11 12:38:55.467 332  
etc.
```

Here's what I want the results to look like, except with the blanks filled in:

```
declare @FirstDay smalldatetime = '20180711', 
        @LastDay  smalldatetime = '20180711';

select top (24*2*datediff(day, @FirstDay, dateadd(day,1,@LastDay)))
  dateadd(minute, 30*(row_number() over (order by (select NULL))-1), 
@FirstDay) as IntervalStartTime
  , 0 as resourceid, '' as eventtype, 0 as SecWithinInterval
into ##Interval
from master.dbo.spt_values;
```

Here's the create table/insert:

```
create table source_data (resourceid int, eventtype int, eventstartdatetime 
datetime
    , eventenddatetime datetime, duration int)

insert into source_data values
(16278,6,2018-07-11 10:53:58.163,2018-07-11 11:03:58.163,600),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 11:03:58.163,2018-07-11 11:16:29.970,751),  
(16278,4,2018-07-11 11:16:29.970,2018-07-11 11:16:33.330,4),  
(16278,5,2018-07-11 11:16:33.330,2018-07-11 11:24:06.977,453),  
(16278,6,2018-07-11 11:24:06.977,2018-07-11 11:31:31.633,445),  
(16278,7,2018-07-11 11:31:31.633,2018-07-11 11:31:31.633,0),  
(16278,1,2018-07-11 12:30:44.020,2018-07-11 17:15:55.173,17111),  
(16278,2,2018-07-11 12:30:44.023,2018-07-11 12:33:23.437,159),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 12:33:23.437,2018-07-11 12:38:55.467,332),  
(16278,4,2018-07-11 12:38:55.467,2018-07-11 12:38:58.677,3),  
(16278,5,2018-07-11 12:38:58.677,2018-07-11 12:45:09.793,371),  
(16278,6,2018-07-11 12:45:09.793,2018-07-11 12:47:20.173,131),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 12:47:20.173,2018-07-11 12:54:51.057,451), 
(16278,4,2018-07-11 12:54:51.057,2018-07-11 12:54:53.383,2),  
(16278,5,2018-07-11 12:54:53.383,2018-07-11 12:59:27.373,274),  
(16278,6,2018-07-11 12:59:27.373,2018-07-11 13:02:25.813,178),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 13:02:25.813,2018-07-11 13:02:49.173,24),  
(16278,4,2018-07-11 13:02:49.173,2018-07-11 13:02:51.490,2),  
(16278,5,2018-07-11 13:02:51.490,2018-07-11 13:05:30.453,159),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 13:05:30.453,2018-07-11 13:05:30.453,0),  
(16278,4,2018-07-11 13:05:30.453,2018-07-11 13:05:33.183,3),  
(16278,5,2018-07-11 13:05:33.183,2018-07-11 13:15:55.777,622),  
(16278,6,2018-07-11 13:15:55.777,2018-07-11 13:16:18.970,23),  
(16278,2,2018-07-11 13:16:18.970,2018-07-11 13:23:32.787,434),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 13:23:32.787,2018-07-11 13:28:12.907,280),  
(16278,4,2018-07-11 13:28:12.907,2018-07-11 13:28:16.073,4),  
(16278,5,2018-07-11 13:28:16.073,2018-07-11 13:32:47.177,271),  
(16278,6,2018-07-11 13:32:47.177,2018-07-11 13:37:45.500,298),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 13:37:45.500,2018-07-11 13:43:59.183,374),  
(16278,4,2018-07-11 13:43:59.183,2018-07-11 13:44:01.507,2),  
(16278,5,2018-07-11 13:44:01.507,2018-07-11 13:50:04.983,363),  
(16278,6,2018-07-11 13:50:04.983,2018-07-11 13:50:43.860,39),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 13:50:43.860,2018-07-11 13:57:21.817,398),  
(16278,4,2018-07-11 13:57:21.817,2018-07-11 13:57:24.177,3),  
(16278,5,2018-07-11 13:57:24.177,2018-07-11 14:07:57.677,633),  
(16278,6,2018-07-11 14:07:57.677,2018-07-11 14:14:08.553,371),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 14:14:08.553,2018-07-11 14:28:57.117,889),  
(16278,4,2018-07-11 14:28:57.117,2018-07-11 14:28:59.440,2),  
(16278,5,2018-07-11 14:28:59.440,2018-07-11 14:31:50.793,171),  
(16278,6,2018-07-11 14:31:50.793,2018-07-11 14:33:08.727,78),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 14:33:08.727,2018-07-11 14:38:30.820,322),  
(16278,2,2018-07-11 14:38:30.820,2018-07-11 14:44:22.197,352),  
(16278,2,2018-07-11 14:44:22.197,2018-07-11 15:01:45.453,1043),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 15:01:45.453,2018-07-11 15:13:38.823,713),  
(16278,4,2018-07-11 15:13:38.823,2018-07-11 15:13:42.247,4),  
(16278,5,2018-07-11 15:13:42.247,2018-07-11 15:18:57.147,315),  
(16278,6,2018-07-11 15:18:57.147,2018-07-11 15:19:12.297,15),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 15:19:12.297,2018-07-11 15:29:43.060,631),  
(16278,4,2018-07-11 15:29:43.060,2018-07-11 15:29:46.160,3),  
(16278,5,2018-07-11 15:29:46.160,2018-07-11 15:30:37.130,51),  
(16278,6,2018-07-11 15:30:37.130,2018-07-11 15:30:44.783,7),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 15:30:44.783,2018-07-11 15:37:46.373,422),  
(16278,4,2018-07-11 15:37:46.373,2018-07-11 15:37:49.080,3),  
(16278,5,2018-07-11 15:37:49.080,2018-07-11 15:43:52.273,363),  
(16278,6,2018-07-11 15:43:52.273,2018-07-11 15:48:54.730,302),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 15:48:54.730,2018-07-11 15:56:47.407,473),  
(16278,4,2018-07-11 15:56:47.407,2018-07-11 15:56:49.820,2),  
(16278,5,2018-07-11 15:56:49.820,2018-07-11 16:01:40.780,291),  
(16278,6,2018-07-11 16:01:40.780,2018-07-11 16:04:02.403,142),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 16:04:02.403,2018-07-11 16:20:53.963,1011),  
(16278,4,2018-07-11 16:20:53.963,2018-07-11 16:21:00.817,7),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 16:21:00.817,2018-07-11 16:35:54.190,894),  
(16278,4,2018-07-11 16:35:54.190,2018-07-11 16:35:56.473,2),  
(16278,5,2018-07-11 16:35:56.473,2018-07-11 16:38:37.587,161),  
(16278,6,2018-07-11 16:38:37.587,2018-07-11 16:45:29.563,412),  
(16278,3,2018-07-11 16:45:29.563,2018-07-11 16:57:20.893,711),  
(16278,4,2018-07-11 16:57:20.893,2018-07-11 16:57:24.000,4),  
(16278,5,2018-07-11 16:57:24.000,2018-07-11 17:10:22.210,778),  
(16278,6,2018-07-11 17:10:22.210,2018-07-11 17:15:55.173,333),  
(16278,7,2018-07-11 17:15:55.173,2018-07-11 17:15:55.173,0)
```

Thank you all so, so much for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a little bit of "recursion" (with CTEs) to build a timetable and join it with your source_data to find all intersections of intervals. 
In my solution, I did not use your field Duration, because I anyway had to calculate the lengths of the intervals (in seconds). The CTE EventDays "creates" all days (if the query is on more than 100 days, you will have to change the MAXRECURSION option or start with CTEs for bigger intervals like months or even years) and the CTE HalfHours creates all haf-hour-intervals for each of the days to build the timetable:

```
DECLARE @FirstDay smalldatetime = '20180711', 
        @LastDay  smalldatetime = '20180711';

WITH 
  EventDays (EventDay, NextDay, MaxDay) AS (
    SELECT @FirstDay, DATEADD(day, 1, @FirstDay), @LastDay
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NextDay, DATEADD(day, 1, NextDay), MaxDay
    FROM EventDays WHERE NextDay <= MaxDay
  ),
  HalfHours (StartTime, EndTime, MaxTime) AS (
    SELECT EventDay, DATEADD(minute, 30, EventDay), NextDay
    FROM EventDays
    UNION ALL
    SELECT EndTime, DATEADD(minute, 30, EndTime), MaxTime
    FROM HalfHours WHERE EndTime < MaxTime
  )
SELECT ResourceID, EventType, isec.StartTime, isec.EndTime,
  DATEDIFF(second, isec.StartTime, isec.EndTime) AS Duration
FROM source_data sd
  INNER JOIN HalfHours hh 
    ON sd.EventEndDatetime > hh.StartTime AND sd.EventStartDatetime < hh.EndTime
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES ( -- intersection StartTime and EndTime
    CASE
      WHEN sd.EventStartDatetime > hh.StartTime THEN sd.EventStartDatetime 
      ELSE hh.StartTime
    END,
    CASE
      WHEN sd.EventEndDatetime < hh.EndTime THEN sd.EventEndDatetime 
      ELSE hh.EndTime
    END)
  ) isec (StartTime, EndTime)
ORDER BY isec.StartTime;
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I just validated this with a set of source records, and it is spot on.  I can't thank you enough for this, you saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

This example uses a numbers table to derive your intervals. It is a quick and dirty bit of code, and doesn't assume that you have an existing numbers table.  For purposes of this example, your sample data has been loaded into a global temp table named ##source_data.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
-- Create a temporary numbers table to demonstrate its use. 
-- We only need numbers up to 47, but will be creating numbers up to 336 to cover
-- periods of up to a week. This table will also include zero.

Declare @DailyIntervals int = 48,
    @maxDays int = 7

-- This calculates the number of recursive inserts needed to reach your maximum value
-- NOTE: This is based off of manually inserting your first four values into the table first!

DECLARE @loop int
SET @loop = CEILING(LOG(@DailyIntervals * @maxDays, 2))-2
--SELECT @loop

Declare @m int
CREATE TABLE ##Nums (i int primary key clustered);

INSERT INTO ##Nums VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);   -- Seed the table

SET @m = 4

WHILE @loop > 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ##nums SELECT I + @m FROM ##Nums
    SET @m = @@ROWCOUNT * 2 -- max value in table now
    SET @loop = @loop - 1
END

INSERT INTO ##nums Values (0)   -- add the zero value

--SELECT MAX(I) FROM ##Nums

-- Look at July 11th only for now.
DECLARE @BeginDt datetime = '2018-07-11',
    @EndDt datetime = '2018-07-11';

-- Build a working table of half hour intervals
WITH hhrs as (
    SELECT Dateadd(MINUTE, 30 * i, @BeginDt) as StartTm,
        Dateadd(MINUTE, 30 * (i+1), @BeginDt) as EndTm
    FROM ##Nums
    WHERE i BETWEEN 0 and (DateDiff(Day, @BeginDt, @EndDt) * 48 + 47)
    ),
-- Get all of the data except duration
Src as (
    SELECT 
        sd.resourceid,
        sd.eventtype,
        CASE
            WHEN sd.eventstartdatetime <= StartTm
                THEN StartTm
            Else sd.eventstartdatetime
        End as EventStart,
        CASE
            WHEN sd.eventEnddatetime > EndTm
                THEN EndTm
            Else sd.eventenddatetime
        End as EventEnd
    FROM hhrs h
    INNER JOIN ##source_data sd
        ON sd.eventstartdatetime < EndTm
        AND sd.eventenddatetime >= StartTm
    )
-- Final output including duration
SELECT 
    ResourceID,
    EventType,
    EventStart,
    EventEnd,
    DateDiff(SECOND, EventStart, EventEnd) as Duration
FROM Src
ORDER BY EventStart, EventEnd
DROP TABLE ##Nums
```

This is the output I received from your sample data:

```
ResourceID EventType  EventStart                 EventEnd                   Duration
16278        6        2018-07-11 10:53:58.163    2018-07-11 11:00:00.000    362
16278        6        2018-07-11 11:00:00.000    2018-07-11 11:03:58.163    238
16278        3        2018-07-11 11:03:58.163    2018-07-11 11:16:29.970    751
16278        4        2018-07-11 11:16:29.970    2018-07-11 11:16:33.330    4
16278        5        2018-07-11 11:16:33.330    2018-07-11 11:24:06.977    453
16278        6        2018-07-11 11:24:06.977    2018-07-11 11:30:00.000    354
16278        6        2018-07-11 11:30:00.000    2018-07-11 11:31:31.633    91
16278        7        2018-07-11 11:31:31.633    2018-07-11 11:31:31.633    0
16278        1        2018-07-11 12:30:44.020    2018-07-11 13:00:00.000    1756
16278        2        2018-07-11 12:30:44.023    2018-07-11 12:33:23.437    159
16278        3        2018-07-11 12:33:23.437    2018-07-11 12:38:55.467    332
16278        4        2018-07-11 12:38:55.467    2018-07-11 12:38:58.677    3
16278        5        2018-07-11 12:38:58.677    2018-07-11 12:45:09.793    371
16278        6        2018-07-11 12:45:09.793    2018-07-11 12:47:20.173    131
16278        3        2018-07-11 12:47:20.173    2018-07-11 12:54:51.057    451
16278        4        2018-07-11 12:54:51.057    2018-07-11 12:54:53.383    2
16278        5        2018-07-11 12:54:53.383    2018-07-11 12:59:27.373    274
16278        6        2018-07-11 12:59:27.373    2018-07-11 13:00:00.000    33
16278        6        2018-07-11 13:00:00.000    2018-07-11 13:02:25.813    145
16278        1        2018-07-11 13:00:00.000    2018-07-11 13:30:00.000    1800
16278        3        2018-07-11 13:02:25.813    2018-07-11 13:02:49.173    24
16278        4        2018-07-11 13:02:49.173    2018-07-11 13:02:51.490    2
16278        5        2018-07-11 13:02:51.490    2018-07-11 13:05:30.453    159
16278        3        2018-07-11 13:05:30.453    2018-07-11 13:05:30.453    0
16278        4        2018-07-11 13:05:30.453    2018-07-11 13:05:33.183    3
16278        5        2018-07-11 13:05:33.183    2018-07-11 13:15:55.777    622
16278        6        2018-07-11 13:15:55.777    2018-07-11 13:16:18.970    23
16278        2        2018-07-11 13:16:18.970    2018-07-11 13:23:32.787    434
16278        3        2018-07-11 13:23:32.787    2018-07-11 13:28:12.907    280
16278        4        2018-07-11 13:28:12.907    2018-07-11 13:28:16.073    4
16278        5        2018-07-11 13:28:16.073    2018-07-11 13:30:00.000    104
16278        5        2018-07-11 13:30:00.000    2018-07-11 13:32:47.177    167
16278        1        2018-07-11 13:30:00.000    2018-07-11 14:00:00.000    1800
16278        6        2018-07-11 13:32:47.177    2018-07-11 13:37:45.500    298
16278        3        2018-07-11 13:37:45.500    2018-07-11 13:43:59.183    374
16278        4        2018-07-11 13:43:59.183    2018-07-11 13:44:01.507    2
16278        5        2018-07-11 13:44:01.507    2018-07-11 13:50:04.983    363
16278        6        2018-07-11 13:50:04.983    2018-07-11 13:50:43.860    39
16278        3        2018-07-11 13:50:43.860    2018-07-11 13:57:21.817    398
16278        4        2018-07-11 13:57:21.817    2018-07-11 13:57:24.177    3
16278        5        2018-07-11 13:57:24.177    2018-07-11 14:00:00.000    156
16278        5        2018-07-11 14:00:00.000    2018-07-11 14:07:57.677    477
16278        1        2018-07-11 14:00:00.000    2018-07-11 14:30:00.000    1800
16278        6        2018-07-11 14:07:57.677    2018-07-11 14:14:08.553    371
16278        3        2018-07-11 14:14:08.553    2018-07-11 14:28:57.117    889
16278        4        2018-07-11 14:28:57.117    2018-07-11 14:28:59.440    2
16278        5        2018-07-11 14:28:59.440    2018-07-11 14:30:00.000    61
16278        5        2018-07-11 14:30:00.000    2018-07-11 14:31:50.793    110
16278        1        2018-07-11 14:30:00.000    2018-07-11 15:00:00.000    1800
16278        6        2018-07-11 14:31:50.793    2018-07-11 14:33:08.727    78
16278        3        2018-07-11 14:33:08.727    2018-07-11 14:38:30.820    322
16278        2        2018-07-11 14:38:30.820    2018-07-11 14:44:22.197    352
16278        2        2018-07-11 14:44:22.197    2018-07-11 15:00:00.000    938
16278        2        2018-07-11 15:00:00.000    2018-07-11 15:01:45.453    105
16278        1        2018-07-11 15:00:00.000    2018-07-11 15:30:00.000    1800
16278        3        2018-07-11 15:01:45.453    2018-07-11 15:13:38.823    713
16278        4        2018-07-11 15:13:38.823    2018-07-11 15:13:42.247    4
16278        5        2018-07-11 15:13:42.247    2018-07-11 15:18:57.147    315
16278        6        2018-07-11 15:18:57.147    2018-07-11 15:19:12.297    15
16278        3        2018-07-11 15:19:12.297    2018-07-11 15:29:43.060    631
16278        4        2018-07-11 15:29:43.060    2018-07-11 15:29:46.160    3
16278        5        2018-07-11 15:29:46.160    2018-07-11 15:30:00.000    14
16278        5        2018-07-11 15:30:00.000    2018-07-11 15:30:37.130    37
16278        1        2018-07-11 15:30:00.000    2018-07-11 16:00:00.000    1800
16278        6        2018-07-11 15:30:37.130    2018-07-11 15:30:44.783    7
16278        3        2018-07-11 15:30:44.783    2018-07-11 15:37:46.373    422
16278        4        2018-07-11 15:37:46.373    2018-07-11 15:37:49.080    3
16278        5        2018-07-11 15:37:49.080    2018-07-11 15:43:52.273    363
16278        6        2018-07-11 15:43:52.273    2018-07-11 15:48:54.730    302
16278        3        2018-07-11 15:48:54.730    2018-07-11 15:56:47.407    473
16278        4        2018-07-11 15:56:47.407    2018-07-11 15:56:49.820    2
16278        5        2018-07-11 15:56:49.820    2018-07-11 16:00:00.000    191
16278        5        2018-07-11 16:00:00.000    2018-07-11 16:01:40.780    100
16278        1        2018-07-11 16:00:00.000    2018-07-11 16:30:00.000    1800
16278        6        2018-07-11 16:01:40.780    2018-07-11 16:04:02.403    142
16278        3        2018-07-11 16:04:02.403    2018-07-11 16:20:53.963    1011
16278        4        2018-07-11 16:20:53.963    2018-07-11 16:21:00.817    7
16278        3        2018-07-11 16:21:00.817    2018-07-11 16:30:00.000    540
16278        3        2018-07-11 16:30:00.000    2018-07-11 16:35:54.190    354
16278        1        2018-07-11 16:30:00.000    2018-07-11 17:00:00.000    1800
16278        4        2018-07-11 16:35:54.190    2018-07-11 16:35:56.473    2
16278        5        2018-07-11 16:35:56.473    2018-07-11 16:38:37.587    161
16278        6        2018-07-11 16:38:37.587    2018-07-11 16:45:29.563    412
16278        3        2018-07-11 16:45:29.563    2018-07-11 16:57:20.893    711
16278        4        2018-07-11 16:57:20.893    2018-07-11 16:57:24.000    4
16278        5        2018-07-11 16:57:24.000    2018-07-11 17:00:00.000    156
16278        5        2018-07-11 17:00:00.000    2018-07-11 17:10:22.210    622
16278        1        2018-07-11 17:00:00.000    2018-07-11 17:15:55.173    955
16278        6        2018-07-11 17:10:22.210    2018-07-11 17:15:55.173    333
16278        7        2018-07-11 17:15:55.173    2018-07-11 17:15:55.173    0
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this is entirely my fault for not being clear.  Do you see the second code block above?  That's what I need the output to look like (except in the code block, I'm writing to a temp table, and then fail to select from it).  The desired output would use the source data as given in the create table/insert into block, then perform sql functions upon it to create an out put as in the second code block, which is to say, the one that starts with:   declare @FirstDay smalldatetime = '20180711', etc, but fails to end with the critical "select * from ##interval".

Comment: The output would have an IntervalStartTime column that goes from timestamp 00:00:00 - 00:30:00 in row 1, then 00:30:00 - 01:00:00 in row 2, etc., up to row 48, which would have timestamp 23:30:00.  Then, for each of these rows, there would be a resourceid, eventtype & SecondsWithinTheInterval.  It's ok to repeat the IntervalTimeStart, as later the data subset would be uniquely defined by IntervalStartTime, ResourceID & EventType.  Data will be used in SSRS report, in which user will select date range, eventtype & resourceid from a picklist.

Comment: And my main problem is how to handle the case where an event starts in one interval (say, 11:00:00) and has some amount of duration in seconds, but then, overlaps into 11:30:00, has, obviously, 1800 seconds of duration in that one, then overlaps into a third interval, 12:00:00, and has some number of seconds duration in that interval.  The events are agent status events in a call center, and we want to look at half hour intervals to see what agents are doing so we can manage workflow.